# Display Toast After Clicking List

Tags: android, listview, toast

I'm trying to make an app which displays a listview, and when you click on a specific item in that list, it will display a toast with specific information.

So far example, I got this code from [this site](//http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html):

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

So how would I modify the code, for example, to display a toast containing information about Android when one clicks "android" in the list? And of course, then a different toast containing different info will be displayed when one clicks on "iPhone" etc.

Thanks for any help you can give :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make `String[] values` a class variable .

toast.show() is missing .

```
Toast.makeText(this, values[position] + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Updating**

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity 
{

    private String[] values ;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
         values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(this, values[position]+ " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
```

Comment: okay thanks, but how do I make it display a toast specific to the item which i clicked?

Comment: sorry i'm a bit of a noob, how do I do that?

Comment: now accept and close if it works . more you will learn through yourself more you will enjoy coding  , so avoid such basic questions in  future

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

  private String[] _values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2" };
  private String[] _details = new String[] { "Android Details", "iPhone Details",   
        "WindowsMobile Details", "Blackberry Details", "WebOS Details", "Ubuntu 
        Details", "Windows7 Details", "Max OS X Details", "Linux Details", "OS/2 Details" };

  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, _values);
     setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
       Toast.makeText(this, _details[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Hope that helps. Happy coding!